# minecraft installation error

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I have tried to reinstall Minecraft but when opening the launcher for the first time it gives me the error *"Unable to update Minecraft launcher"*, this is what my native log reads as

```
########################################################
Native Launcher Version: 63
Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium
Application Hash: 040e43e8a8b004992c0e5d3b9c7ff24efdb5486b
Java Version: 
x64: 1
Starting download of: https://launchermeta.mojang.com/mc/launcher.json
Created pFile
Content length is 00AF51E0
Got 200 from server
Download successful
Runtime outdated!
Runtime version should be should be 1.8.0_25
Game launcher outdated!
Hash should be c3faf74aa9ca3b7f7beed0c16b7198747e6b7aaf
Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/jre/win-64/1.8.0_25/bdca00e1c2a1f2c23c9a77b65188b788d475a603/jre-win-64-1.8.0_25.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/jre/win-64/1.8.0_25/bdca00e1c2a1f2c23c9a77b65188b788d475a603/jre-win-64-1.8.0_25.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/jre/win-64/1.8.0_25/bdca00e1c2a1f2c23c9a77b65188b788d475a603/jre-win-64-1.8.0_25.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Deleted game/_tmpJava.lzma
Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/jar/9a53e5401d42e000c6a14682f539e20b1f74e266/launcher.jar.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/jar/9a53e5401d42e000c6a14682f539e20b1f74e266/launcher.jar.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Starting download of: http://launcher.mojang.com/mc/launcher/jar/9a53e5401d42e000c6a14682f539e20b1f74e266/launcher.jar.lzma
Encountered internet exception 12002: The operation timed out

Deleted game/launchertmp.jar.lzma
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: what version of Java do you have? it looks like it's complaining about that and/or your launcher being out of date. Also, `operation timed out` means something is wrong with you connection to the internet. make sure you don't have firewall causing issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a minecraft crash support question.

Comment: @GnomeSlice - This question is on-topic - we allow questions troubleshooting *vanilla* Minecraft only (i.e. no mods).

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors I could pick up on in the log. The first is that it indicates that your runtime is outdated. I believe that means your Java version is out of date. Try to update it. The second error is the operation timed out one, which means that you have no/poor/spotty internet connection, or that you have a firewall up. Try to either get to a better internet hotspot and/or turn off your firewall.

Comment: It should be noted that whether their java is x86-32 or x86-64 may cause that error. I believe I ran into this when I upgraded to Java 1.8, it wouldn't accept the 32bit version forcing me to run the 64bit version (which I needed to do anyway for other reasons)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're Java is out of date. Try installing the latest version then test it out at https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp to see if you actually have it.

Additionally, you might want to turn off you're firewall, there usually an option to disable for 15 minutes. That should be enough time if you have decent internet. If not, there are longer periods of time you can select.